# Apache install on Debian: configuring CGI

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, cgi

I installed CGI via the package manager and enabled the mod, but two hours later I still cant get it to work.

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/

        <Directory /var/www/cgi-bin/>
            AllowOverride None
            Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ 
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

CGI is enabled. When I browse to `mydomain.com/cgi-bin/` it goes to `/usr/lib/cgi` (I believe) instead.

```
root@zeus:~# a2enmod cgi
Module cgi already enabled
root@zeus:~# apt-get install php5-cgi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php5-cgi is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@zeus:~# sudo service apache2 restart
[....] Restarting web server: apache2[Wed Apr 23 20:20:28 2014] [warn] The ScriptAlias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default at line 29 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier ScriptAlias.
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
... waiting [Wed Apr 23 20:20:29 2014] [warn] The ScriptAlias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default at line 29 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier ScriptAlias.
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
. ok
```

Comment: You have two `ScriptAlias` directives, of which only one will be used. Maybe you need to decide on which one to use, or alias one of them to something other than `/cgi-bin/`